# Address dimension or not?

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

My team is debating internally whether or not we should be creating a separate dimension of address information. The use case is a warehouse for a mail marketing agency, so address is quite important for a multitude of reasons.

We have a couple of pieces of address information flowing in (like Bank address, Customer Address (Our Client's customers), Mailing List Address (or Manifests), And Client Address. We might also get information in bits and pieces from other information that we might need to tie to a specific customer based on address comparisons.

We also do geocoding on our addresses to augment, standardize and validate our addresses that come in.

In total, we are storing the following fields for any given address:

```
DeliveryLine1 
DeliveryLine2 
LastLine 
DeliveryPointBarcode 
StreetNumber 
ApartmentNumber 
ApartmentUnitType 
StreetName 
StreetSuffix 
Locality 
Region 
ZipCode 
ZipCodePlusFour 
DeliveryPoint 
DeliveryPointCheckpointDigit 
Latitude 
Longitude 
RecordType 
ZipType 
CountyFIPS 
CarrierRoute 
ResidentialDeliveryIndicator 
Precision 
DPV 
Vacant 
Active 
EWS
```

thats 27 fields in total.

My colleague is of the opinion that address should go into each dimension (Customer, Bank, Client, Manifest). While I agree that in simple cases where we store Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip it would make sense, but we store a significant amount of added information about an address, with more bits and pieces being added later on (potentially). I make the contention that something like this would be better suited as a separate dimension. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Looking from dimensional modelling point of view, your fact tables should answer to this question. If your [mail marketing] facts relates to addresses then go ahead and make Address as a separate dimension. I mean, if you do [a mail marketing] to Banks, to Customers, to Mailing List Addresses and Clients and want to analyze information based on Geo information (that is on Address) then it should be created as a separated dimension. However, if you [usually] mail market only your CLients and use an address for other purpose, i.e to find nearly Customer, Banks,etc, then I don't see much value to make an Address as a dimension. In essence, if your facts are related to Addresses to the same level as targets (Banks, Customers, Mailing List Addresses, Clients) then it should be a dimension. If that means nothing but just an attribute of Bank, Customer, Mailing List Address or Client then no need to go with a dimension.